# How to enable unsafe volume warming in android 7?

Tags: audio

I have a Huawei P9 lite smartphone with android 7. I disabled the unsafe volume warning by accident and I cannot find any settings to enable it again. I checked settings and then sounds, however, I cannot find an option to enable it again.

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: I got a notification that had two options, "Cancel" and "O.K". I chose O.K and then it was disabled.

Comment: Phone model? We can not help much without some basic informations

Comment: I added the smartphone model.